# Ubuntu 18.04 - system forcely restarted, all drivers are gone (unclaimed)

Tags: 18.04, drivers

by mistake, the system was forcely shutdown (long press on the power key), when I restarted the system, all the drivers are unclaimed

```
sudo lshw | grep UNCLAIMED
        *-display UNCLAIMED
        *-multimedia:0 UNCLAIMED
              *-usb:2 UNCLAIMED
              *-usb:3 UNCLAIMED
              *-usb:4 UNCLAIMED
        *-communication UNCLAIMED
        *-multimedia:1 UNCLAIMED
           *-generic UNCLAIMED
           *-network UNCLAIMED
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
```

**all the drivers are pre-installed with ubuntu**

Comment: Did SysRq key combinations fail to shutdown?  After a failure of some sort, the first thing I do is `fsck` (*file-system check*) my partitions from 'live' media to ensure the system is clean before it's booted normally. This usually fixes issues in my experience, is your *fs* clean?

Comment: everything seems fine, only the drivers weren't there

Comment: For a `install --reinstall` to help, this reads to me as a problem occurred, and you just *white-washed* the symptoms rather than fixing the issue, and I'd worry about how reliable the system is. At best your `install --reinstall` solution just caused a `dpkg-reconfigure` to be run (which fixed your issue), but what else is corrupted??

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone had the same situation, I had reinstalled ubuntu common drivers

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-drivers-common
```

then restarted the machine.